How to Load Background Images from the Public Directory in CSS with Vite in Laravel?
I'm working on a Laravel project and using Vite for asset management. I have a situation where the logo image is stored in the resources folder, while the demo images are kept in the public folder. I want to set a background image in a CSS file located in resources, but the image itself is in the public folder.
How can I configure the CSS file to correctly load the background image from the public folder when using Vite?

This question is similar to: Linking a CSS image URL in laravel. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To load a background image from the public folder in a CSS file managed by Vite:
Hardcode the Public Path: Use the direct URL in your CSS:
.example-class {
    background-image: url('/path/to/image/in/public/folder/image.jpg');
}

Use Blade asset Helper: Reference the image in your Blade template:
<style>
    .example-class {
        background-image: url('{{ asset('path/to/image/in/public/folder/image.jpg') }}');
    }
</style>

Move Images to resources Folder: Place images in resources/images and reference them with Vite:
.example-class {
    background-image: url('/images/image.jpg');
}

--- OR ---
S3 Image Reference in CSS
Use the Storage Facade in Blade: In your Blade template, dynamically generate the
S3 URL:
<style>
    .example-class {
        background-image: url('{{ Storage::url('path/to/image/on/s3/image.jpg') }}');
    }
</style>

Configure Storage Disk: Make sure your filesystems.php is configured correctly for S3:
'disks' => [
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
],

Use this approach for S3-hosted images to ensure the URL is generated correctly and is accessible.
